# How to include cordova camera plugin in angular2 - cordova hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, hybrid-mobile-app

Tried Accessing the device camera through the cordova camera plugin in the hybrid app but it was not working. Can anyone guide that how to include the cordova camera plugin in the hybrid app (here is the link for which i tried - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

Answer (score -1):

in this blog I found a solution that works for me http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-using-the-camera-with-ionic-native/